# ios intercept animation values

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewanimation

during an ios animation of `[UIView animatWithDuration...]` how can I intercept the animation values during the animation?

Here's my current (not working) solution:

```
#import "FooterSelectionView.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation FooterSelectionView

@synthesize displayLink;

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        
        selector = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selector.png"]];
        [self addSubview:selector];
        
        [self setSelectorFrame:CGRectMake(700, 0, selector.frame.size.width, selector.frame.size.height)];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIImage *bg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"overlayArea.png"];
    [bg drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 957, 127) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1];
    
    [selector.image drawInRect:selector.frame blendMode:kCGBlendModeOverlay alpha:1];
}

-(void)step {
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
    
    NSLog(@"%@", @"step");
}

- (void)setSelectorFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(step)];
    [displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5 animations:^{
        selector.frame = frame;
        //self.alpha = 0
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
        
        [self.displayLink invalidate];
        self.displayLink = nil;
        NSLog(@"%@", @"stop");
    }];
}

@end
```

I see the actual image view move, but the "drawn" version with overlay only goes immediately to the target value. I'd like to be able to tell the "drawn" version to go wherever the actual selector view is. How can I do this?

## edit

When I `NSLog` the `selector.frame.origin.x` I've noticed that the value is always `0`. I can see that the selector is animation on the screen, so what gives?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a few mistakes here:

1. Don't try to do frame-by-frame animation with drawRect, it's really not fast enough for this because Core Graphics isn't hardware accelerated (it may look fine on the simulator - it won't on a real device).

   If you want to animate an image's rectangle, use a UIImageView and animate it with normal UIView animation methods.

   If you can't see a way to achieve your animation using normal animation methods, you can do it frame by frame using displayLink, but you should still do your drawing by just updating the frame of a UIImageView instead of drawing the image directly in drawRect.
2. UIView animation doesn't animate the `view.frame` property directly. If you set the `view.frame` it sets immediately to whatever value you specify, even when animating. Trying to sync a frame-by-frame animation to the frame of another view as it animates therefor won't work.

   To get the actual mid-animation value of the animating view frame, you need to look at the `view.layer.presentationLayer.frame` instead - this is the value that animates. The `view.frame` is actually just a getter method that returns the `view.layer.modelLayer.frame`, which is always set to whatever value `view.frame` was last set to.

Comment: I'm dealing with an `Overlay` blend mode. The blend mode has to have the background to "blend" correctly. If I do the selector image in a different view, then the blend mode will not work at all (that's how blend modes are as I'm sure you know). So I'm trying to devise a way to get them in the same UIObject, but only give the appearance of having the selector move. It's tricky business :(

Comment: FYI, I just ran this on the ipad and because I'm doing such a small piece for overlay animation it runs at full frames. Thanks for your awesome answers, you are certainly a valuable asset to SOF's ios q & a.

Comment: +1 just for the `view.layer.presentationLayer.frame` part, extremely usefull

Comment: You are a life saver buddy.Massive respect for point no 2